# Requests to AWS using Django not using correct parameters on all files

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a Django application that upon loading the admin, only receives 4 out of 6 of the necessary static files. The difference between the 4 successful and the 2 failed is that the following paramters are not present in the failed requests:

- `X-Amz-Algorithm`
- `X-Amz-Credential`
- `X-Amz-Date`
- `X-Amz-Expires`
- `X-Amz-SignedHeaders`
- `X-Amz-Signature`

However the parameters are present in the request headers referer.
Also it is consistently the same 2 files. And yes they exist as I will mention further down in this question.

I installed `django-storages` and `boto3` to work with AWS.

Here are the relevant settings from settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'storages',
    ...
]

AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'my-access-key'
AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'my-secret-access-key'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'my-bucket-01'

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'eu-west-2'
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = 's3v4'
AWS_S3_ADDRESSING_STYLE = "virtual"
```

A successful request:

> https:// my-bucket-01.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/admin/css/responsive.css?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=my-access-key%2F20220217%2Feu-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220217T212138Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=31bc0e43fcc693f70c7662432ee6d88d8358652894611a0f7387ac35febf5ef9

A failed request:

> https:// my-bucket-01.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/admin/css/fonts.css

Failed requests referer:

> https:// my-bucket-01.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/admin/css/base.css?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=my-access-key%2F20220217%2Feu-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220217T212138Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=af8fb82686dd0dcc2600eebdf9ceecec482dd44be02a3c3f3a9b793f96cee617

I went to the link in the referer and it worked.

So my question is either:

- Why do only some of my requests include the correct parameters and how do I get them to use the correct ones?

or

- How do I force the requests to use the referers?

Comment: I recommend using `S3StaticStorage` instead of `S3Boto3Storage` for static files with a public accessible bucket.

Comment: Does base.css import fonts.css? Guessing that your static file serving is OK for top-level files but not for anything embedded as a reference/import within them.

Comment: @Marco - I tried changing the storage and making the bucket public but now I can't get the files at all.

Comment: @jarmod - Yes it does import fonts.css. Is that why?

Comment: It would seem that way. The hint was that the referer for fonts.css was base.css. I don't use Django storages with S3 but research how it generates pre-signed URLs for top-level and for referenced static files. BTW I presume these files are all private, which is why you're using pre-signed URLs. If the entire website was public, you wouldn't need to do this at all.

Comment: Unrelated, assuming this is running on EC2 or other AWS compute, you would ideally provide the S3 storage layer with temporary credentials associated with an IAM role that the compute was launched with, not with persistent IAM user credentials which you're doing right now.

Comment: @jarmod - How should I go about still including the files since removing the imports simply means I still don't have access to them?

Comment: @Shaun most of the time it doesn't make much sense to serve static assets from a private bucket. MAke the static assets bucket public and use `S3StaticStorage`.